# Specify custom plural form in glossaries does not work

Tags: glossaries

Why does not the plural form work in `glossaries`? Sorry for bad indentation

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{chscite2}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{isomath}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\vectorsym}
\newcommand{\mat}{\matrixsym}
\newcommand{\ten}{\tensorsym}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[per-mode=fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[toc,xindy]{glossaries}
\newcommand*{\glossfirstformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{\textit{See}: \glsseelist{#2}} 
\newacronymstyle{myacro}{%
    \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}%
{%
\GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
\renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[1]{%
\glossfirstformat{\glsentrylong{##1}}\space(\glsentryshort{##1})%}
\renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
\glossfirstformat{\Glsentrylong{##1}}\space(\glsentryshort{##1})%
}%
\renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
 \glossfirstformat{\glsentrylongpl{##1}}\space(\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
}%
\renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
\glossfirstformat{\Glsentrylongpl{##1}}\space
  (\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
}%
}
\setacronymstyle{myacro}
\defglsentryfmt{%
\ifglshaslong{\glslabel}{%
\glsgenacfmt%
}{%
 \ifglsused{\glslabel}{%
  \glsgenentryfmt%
 }{%
  \glossfirstformat{\glsgenentryfmt}%
  }%
 }%6
}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}{\sffamily}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
\newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
 description={#6},#1
 }
\newacronym[see={[See:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}
}

\usepackage{import}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}  
{\sffamily{\textbf{Figure}}}}
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{%
  \figurename~\thefigure%
%  \autodot% DELETED
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathbbm{N}}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\ensuremath{\mathbbm{Z}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\ensuremath{\mathbbm{Q}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbbm{R}}}
\newcommand{\C}{\ensuremath{\mathbbm{C}}}
\newcommand{\rd}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{d}}}
\newcommand{\id}{\ensuremath{\,\rd}}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\mleftright
\newcommand{\umltitle}[1]{\footnotesize{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\umlentry}[1]{\footnotesize{#1}}
\newcommand{\umlabstract}[1]{\footnotesize{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\figuretext}[1]{\footnotesize{#1}}
\newcommand{\textclassname}[1]{\mbox{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\bigo}[1]{\mathcal{O}\left(#1 \right)}
```

In the document

```
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{polymesh}{name={polygon mesh},plural={polygon meshes},description={A storage model that is frequently used in 3D computer graphics to represent 3D objects}}\glspl{polymesh}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Output from `\glspl{polymesh}`

> polygon meshs

pdflatex --version

> pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
>
> kpathsea version 6.1.1
>
> Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX). There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and the Lesser GNU General Public License. For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
>
> Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>
> Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
>   Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
>   Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5

xindy --version

> xindy release: unknown
>
> xindy script version: 1.16
>
> xindy kernel version: 3.0
>
> CLISP version 2.49 (2010-07-07) (built on brownie.buildd [127.0.1.1])
>       architecture: X86_64

Glossaries version:

> Package: glossaries 2014/01/20 v4.03 (NLCT)

Build commands:

```
rm -f output/report.*
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory output report.tex
xindy -q -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M "output/report" -t "output/report.glg" -o "output/report.gls" "output/report.glo"
bibtex output/report.aux
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory output report.tex
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory output report.tex
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory output report.tex
```

Minimal example provided by Nicola:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[toc,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand*{\glossfirstformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{\textit{See}:
\glsseelist{#2}} 
\newacronymstyle{myacro}{%
    \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}%
{%
\GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
\renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[1]{%
\glossfirstformat{\glsentrylong{##1}}\space(\glsentryshort{##1})%
}
\renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
\glossfirstformat{\Glsentrylong{##1}}\space(\glsentryshort{##1})%
}%
\renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
 \glossfirstformat{\glsentrylongpl{##1}}\space(\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
}%
\renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
\glossfirstformat{\Glsentrylongpl{##1}}\space
  (\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
}%
}
\setacronymstyle{myacro}
\defglsentryfmt{%
\ifglshaslong{\glslabel}{%
\glsgenacfmt%
}{%
 \ifglsused{\glslabel}{%
  \glsgenentryfmt%
 }{%
  \glossfirstformat{\glsgenentryfmt}%
  }%
 }%6
}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}{\sffamily}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {%
\newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
 description={#6},#1
 }
\newacronym[see={[See:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}
}

\newglossaryentry{polymesh}{name={polygon mesh},plural={polygon
meshes},description={A storage model that is frequently used in 3D
computer graphics to represent 3D objects}}

\begin{document}

\glspl{polymesh}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you turn the code into a full compilable document showing the issue?

Comment: I get the expected output using `glossaries` v4.15, so either you have some extra code you haven't told us about (which is why a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is required) or you may be using an old version that has some bug that's been fixed.

Comment: That is all that fiddles with the glossaries package. I thought the custom acronym stuff could make it bail out. BTW, how do I figure out what version of glossaries I have? [texlive-latex-extra version 2013.20140215-2]

Comment: You can find the version number from the log file. (Search for `glossaries.sty`, or add `\listfiles` to your document and it will add all the version information at the end of the transcript.) It would help if you could add `\documentclass`, `\makeglossaries` and `\begin{document}\glspl{polymesh}\end{document}` to the code you posted to make it a minimal working example that illustrates the problem. That way we know we're both working with the same code.

Comment: You have an old version of `glossaries`. It may be related to [Acronyms defined in document body result in wrong firstplural](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&category=glossaries&key=54). Move `\newglossaryentry` to the preamble (before `\begin{document}`) and try again. (And possibly also update your version of `glossaries.sty`.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Upgrading to 4.15 did not help. The declaration outside the environment declaration worked. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Since the question has been closed I can't answer it yet, but I've added a minimal working example to your question. Please copy and paste it into a test file and say what output this produces. For me it produces "polygon meshes".

Comment: Regarding defining entries in the preamble instead of the document environment, please see [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).

Comment: On the other hand, define on first use is a good practice in C++. You have done a good job by emitting error when an entry is not defined before use. Your example works as expected.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Apparently your edit about six months ago lead to reopening of the question. Will you add an answer 'now'?

Comment: ~ ( TeX = C++ ) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[toc,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand*{\glossfirstformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{\textit{See}:
\glsseelist{#2}} 
\newacronymstyle{myacro}{%
    \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}%
{%
\GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
\renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[1]{%
\glossfirstformat{\glsentrylong{##1}}\space(\glsentryshort{##1})%
}
\renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
\glossfirstformat{\Glsentrylong{##1}}\space(\glsentryshort{##1})%
}%
\renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
 \glossfirstformat{\glsentrylongpl{##1}}\space(\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
}%
\renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
\glossfirstformat{\Glsentrylongpl{##1}}\space
  (\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
}%
}
\setacronymstyle{myacro}
\defglsentryfmt{%
\ifglshaslong{\glslabel}{%
\glsgenacfmt%
}{%
 \ifglsused{\glslabel}{%
  \glsgenentryfmt%
 }{%
  \glossfirstformat{\glsgenentryfmt}%
  }%
 }%6
}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}{\sffamily}

\newglossaryentry{polymesh}{name={polygon mesh},plural={polygon
meshes},description={A storage model that is frequently used in 3D
computer graphics to represent 3D objects}}

\begin{document}

\glspl{polymesh}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Things to check:

- make sure you have an up-to-date version of the `glossaries` package;
- make sure your definitions are in the preamble;
- if you are using `\newacronym` instead of `\newglossaryentry`, then use `\setacronymstyle` (as in the example) and the `longplural` or `shortplural` keys, as appropriate, to override the default long or short plural forms.